# css and meteor 0.7.1 : property missing

Tags: meteor

today i've updated my app from meteor 0.7.0.1 to 0.7.1.1 and, i have a crash of my app because of my app.css file.

Here is the part that fail :

```
@media screen (min-width: 1200px) {
   #BtnCollapseStatusFilterBar { /* IT'S HERE JUST BEFORE THE EMBRACE */
     display: block;
   }
 }
```

And the message is :

```
=> Errors prevented startup:
App 21289 stdout:
App 21289 stdout: While building the application:
App 21289 stdout: app.css: property missing ':' near line 10:31
App 21289 stdout:
App 21289 stdout: => Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

I don't really understand the problem because i'm not a CSS master.

Any idea ?

Here is the full CSS

```
@-webkit-viewport{width:device-width}
@-moz-viewport{width:device-width}
@-ms-viewport{width:device-width}
@-o-viewport{width:device-width}
@viewport{width:device-width}

@grid-float-breakpoint: @screen-desktop;

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  #BtnCollapseStatusFilterBar {
    display: block;
  }

  #navbar-status-filterbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

/* CSS declarations go here */

#nprogress .bar {
  z-index: 2000; /*bs3 navbar is on 1030*/
  background: #A300FF;
}

body {
  background-image: url(subtlenet2.png);
  background-attachment: repeat;
  /*line-height: 19px;*/
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.blockAd {
  padding-left: 10px;
  min-height: 275px; /* don't work, only if inside style attribute directly in html */
  border: none; /*1px solid grey;*/
  border-radius: 10px 0 10px 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  width:208px;
  background: rgba(256, 256, 256, .7);
}

/* new ad */
.blockAd.newAd {
  border-top: solid turquoise;
}

/* no more new */
.blockAd.viewedAd {
  border-top: solid mediumseagreen;
}

/* detail open */
.blockAd.openedAd {
  border-top: solid aquamarine;
}

/* no more interesting */
.blockAd.removedAd {
  border-top: solid orange;
}

/* went to product */
.blockAd.visitedAd {
  border-top: solid skyblue;
}

/* owner contacted */
.blockAd.starAd {
  border-top: solid orangered;
}

.blockAd .btn-toolbar {
  padding-top:5px;
}

.blockAnnonce .infos {
  height: 110px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.blockAd .infosHead {
  color:black;
}

.blockAd .centerContentImage {
  float:right;
  width:100%;
  padding-right:5px;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

.blockAd .centerContentImage img {
  max-height: 110px;
  max-width:140px;
}

.blockAd .centerContentImage button.OpenDetailAd {
  height:105px;
  margin-left:3px;
}

/* background of geo zone */
.navbar-collapse.navbar-location-collapse {
  max-height: inherit;
}

/* title and buttons up / down non clickable */
.navbar-location-collapse ul {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

/*
a.BtnConfiguration span {
  width: 44px;
  height: 34px;
}*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like version 0.7.1 throws errors where the syntax of your CSS is incorrect rather just ignoring the relevant rule, as was previously the case.  There was probably always a problem there, it just wasn't raised before 0.7.1.

I'd put your entire CSS file in [CSS Lint](http://csslint.net/) and see what it comes up with - it's possible that there's a problem on a different line to the one that Meteor is suggesting, or at least a problem somewhere.

**UPDATE**
Looking at the full code, you have at least one LESS variable in your file (`@grid-float-breakpoint`).  I don't use LESS, but as far as I'm aware you need to give LESS files a `.less` filename extension to tell Meteor to compile them to CSS, otherwise the rules will fail.  Try changing the filename from `app.css` to `app.less` and see if that works.  Obviously, you need to have the LESS package added too, so `meteor add less` if you haven't done so already.

Comment: thanks for the tips, unfortunately, css Lint doesn't find any error nor warning message. I removed those line from the css file and everything run again. But it's not the solution coz i need those lines.

Comment: In fact if i remove some previous line of the css, then css Lint find more warning. Some of them are "Disallow IDs in selectors", but even if i remove the five lines frome the css i still have some with IDs and it works with...

Comment: Could you post the whole CSS?

Comment: css file content available in original post

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem few hours back. I just missed some property value like this

```
padding-left:""
```

I forgot to give a value and after I gave it worked fine. Check for the same in your CSS.

I think in your app something in 10th line you forgot to give a value for the property like above.